# select-string works on get-content but not directly on invoke-webclient content

Tags: powershell

A part of an automated tool chain needs some input data from a website accessible through a well-documented and working API to fetch data in "CSV" format. The output of the `Invoke-WebRequest` requires some further selection of the response data, since the response not only contains the desired "CSV" data but also some explanatory lines. Here's the data (exact URL to reproduce below):

```
Latitude (deg.): 51.654
Longitude (deg.): 6.606

A               H_hor           A_sun(w)                H_sun(w)                A_sun(s)                H_sun(s)
-180.0          0.8             -180.0          0.0             -180.0          0.0
-172.5          0.8             -165.6          0.0             -172.9          0.0
-165.0          1.1             -152.1          0.0             -165.9          0.0
-157.5          1.1             -140.0          0.0             -158.9          0.0
-150.0          1.1             -129.4          0.0             -152.2          0.0
-142.5          1.5             -120.1          0.0             -145.7          0.0
-135.0          1.5             -112.0          0.0             -139.4          0.0
-127.5          1.5             -104.7          0.0             -133.3          0.0
-120.0          1.5             -98.1           0.0             -127.4          1.6
-112.5          1.5             -91.9           0.0             -121.6          5.4
-105.0          1.5             -86.1           0.0             -116.0          9.5
-97.5           1.5             -80.5           0.0             -110.5          13.8
-90.0           1.5             -74.9           0.0             -105.1          18.2
-82.5           1.5             -69.5           0.0             -99.5           22.7
-75.0           1.5             -64.0           0.0             -93.9           27.3
-67.5           1.1             -58.4           0.0             -88.1           32.0
-60.0           1.1             -52.6           0.0             -81.9           36.6
-52.5           1.1             -46.7           2.0             -75.3           41.2
-45.0           1.1             -40.6           5.2             -68.0           45.6
-37.5           1.1             -34.3           8.0             -59.9           49.8
-30.0           0.0             -27.8           10.4            -50.6           53.6
-22.5           0.4             -21.1           12.3            -40.0           56.9
-15.0           0.4             -14.1           13.7            -27.9           59.5
-7.5            0.4             -7.1            14.6            -14.4           61.2
0.0             0.0             0.0             14.9            0.0             61.8
7.5             0.0             7.1             14.6            14.4            61.2
15.0            0.0             14.1            13.7            27.9            59.5
22.5            0.0             21.1            12.3            40.0            56.9
30.0            0.4             27.8            10.4            50.6            53.6
37.5            0.0             34.3            8.0             59.9            49.8
45.0            0.0             40.6            5.2             68.0            45.6
52.5            0.0             46.7            2.0             75.3            41.2
60.0            0.0             52.6            0.0             81.9            36.6
67.5            0.0             58.4            0.0             88.1            32.0
75.0            0.0             64.0            0.0             93.9            27.3
82.5            0.4             69.5            0.0             99.5            22.7
90.0            0.4             74.9            0.0             105.1           18.2
97.5            0.0             80.5            0.0             110.5           13.8
105.0           0.8             86.1            0.0             116.0           9.5
112.5           0.8             91.9            0.0             121.6           5.4
120.0           0.8             98.1            0.0             127.4           1.6
127.5           0.8             104.7           0.0             133.3           0.0
135.0           0.4             112.0           0.0             139.4           0.0
142.5           0.4             120.1           0.0             145.7           0.0
150.0           0.8             129.4           0.0             152.2           0.0
157.5           0.8             140.0           0.0             158.9           0.0
165.0           0.8             152.1           0.0             165.9           0.0
172.5           0.8             165.6           0.0             172.9           0.0
180.0           0.8             180.0           0.0             180.0           0.0

A: Azimuth (0 = S, 90 = W, -90 = E) (degree)
H_hor: Horizon height (degree)
A_sun(w): Sun azimuth in the winter solstice (Dec 21) (0 = S, 90 = W, -90 = E) (degree)
H_sun(w): Sun height in the winter solstice (Dec 21) (degree)
A_sun(s): Sun azimuth in the summer solstice (June 21) (0 = S, 90 = W, -90 = E) (degree)
H_sun(s): Sun height in the summer solstice (June 21) (degree)

PVGIS (c) European Union, 2001-2021
```

I'd like to only select the lines matching `'^[0-9-]'` (positive and negative numbers). Essentially, selecting the following lines:

```
-180.0          0.8             -180.0          0.0             -180.0          0.0
-172.5          0.8             -165.6          0.0             -172.9          0.0
-165.0          1.1             -152.1          0.0             -165.9          0.0
-157.5          1.1             -140.0          0.0             -158.9          0.0
-150.0          1.1             -129.4          0.0             -152.2          0.0
-142.5          1.5             -120.1          0.0             -145.7          0.0
-135.0          1.5             -112.0          0.0             -139.4          0.0
-127.5          1.5             -104.7          0.0             -133.3          0.0
-120.0          1.5             -98.1           0.0             -127.4          1.6
-112.5          1.5             -91.9           0.0             -121.6          5.4
-105.0          1.5             -86.1           0.0             -116.0          9.5
-97.5           1.5             -80.5           0.0             -110.5          13.8
-90.0           1.5             -74.9           0.0             -105.1          18.2
-82.5           1.5             -69.5           0.0             -99.5           22.7
-75.0           1.5             -64.0           0.0             -93.9           27.3
-67.5           1.1             -58.4           0.0             -88.1           32.0
-60.0           1.1             -52.6           0.0             -81.9           36.6
-52.5           1.1             -46.7           2.0             -75.3           41.2
-45.0           1.1             -40.6           5.2             -68.0           45.6
-37.5           1.1             -34.3           8.0             -59.9           49.8
-30.0           0.0             -27.8           10.4            -50.6           53.6
-22.5           0.4             -21.1           12.3            -40.0           56.9
-15.0           0.4             -14.1           13.7            -27.9           59.5
-7.5            0.4             -7.1            14.6            -14.4           61.2
0.0             0.0             0.0             14.9            0.0             61.8
7.5             0.0             7.1             14.6            14.4            61.2
15.0            0.0             14.1            13.7            27.9            59.5
22.5            0.0             21.1            12.3            40.0            56.9
30.0            0.4             27.8            10.4            50.6            53.6
37.5            0.0             34.3            8.0             59.9            49.8
45.0            0.0             40.6            5.2             68.0            45.6
52.5            0.0             46.7            2.0             75.3            41.2
60.0            0.0             52.6            0.0             81.9            36.6
67.5            0.0             58.4            0.0             88.1            32.0
75.0            0.0             64.0            0.0             93.9            27.3
82.5            0.4             69.5            0.0             99.5            22.7
90.0            0.4             74.9            0.0             105.1           18.2
97.5            0.0             80.5            0.0             110.5           13.8
105.0           0.8             86.1            0.0             116.0           9.5
112.5           0.8             91.9            0.0             121.6           5.4
120.0           0.8             98.1            0.0             127.4           1.6
127.5           0.8             104.7           0.0             133.3           0.0
135.0           0.4             112.0           0.0             139.4           0.0
142.5           0.4             120.1           0.0             145.7           0.0
150.0           0.8             129.4           0.0             152.2           0.0
157.5           0.8             140.0           0.0             158.9           0.0
165.0           0.8             152.1           0.0             165.9           0.0
172.5           0.8             165.6           0.0             172.9           0.0
180.0           0.8             180.0           0.0             180.0           0.0
```

As an example, let's look at the following session explaining my confusion:

```shell
~#@❯ $horizonUrl = 'https://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/api/printhorizon?lat=51.654&lon=6.606&browser=0&outputformat=csv'
~#@❯ $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $horizonUrl
~#@❯ $respcont = $response.Content
~#@❯ $respcontstr = [String[]]$response.Content
~#@❯ $respcontobj = [Object[]]$response.Content
~#@❯ $respcont | Select-String -Pattern "^[0-9-]" -Raw
~#@❯ $respcontstr | Select-String -Pattern "^[0-9-]" -Raw
~#@❯ $respcontobj | Select-String -Pattern "^[0-9-]" -Raw
~#@❯ $respcont.GetType().Name + " " + $respcont.GetType().BaseType                                                     
String System.Object
~#@❯ $respcontstr.GetType().Name + " " + $respcontstr.GetType().BaseType
String[] array
~#@❯ $respcontobj.GetType().Name + " " + $respcontobj.GetType().BaseType
Object[] array

---> No output on the Select-String for the variants above <---

~#@❯ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $horizonUrl -OutFile .\horizon.csv
~#@❯ $gc = (Get-Content .\horizon.csv)
~#@❯ $gc.GetType().Name + " " + $gc.GetType().BaseType                                                                 
Object[] array
~#@❯ $gc | Select-String -Pattern "^[0-9-]" -Raw
-180.0          0.8             -180.0          0.0             -180.0          0.0
-172.5          0.8             -165.6          0.0             -172.9          0.0
-165.0          1.1             -152.1          0.0             -165.9          0.0
-157.5          1.1             -140.0          0.0             -158.9          0.0
-150.0          1.1             -129.4          0.0             -152.2          0.0
-142.5          1.5             -120.1          0.0             -145.7          0.0
-135.0          1.5             -112.0          0.0             -139.4          0.0
-127.5          1.5             -104.7          0.0             -133.3          0.0
[...]

---> Piped through Get-Content, Select-String dumps the desired output <---
```

How come `Select-String` works well together with an intermediate file in piped command chain, however not when used directly, without storing the response content of the `Invoke-WebRequest`?

The explicit type conversion above was my meager attempt at mimicking the data structure of the output of `Get-Content`. All the outputs before the pipe look identical in the console (lines of strings).

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Content` property on the response object you get from `Invoke-WebRequest` is a single multi-line string. `Get-Content` on the other hand returns multiple single-line strings.

You can use the `-split` operator to split on newlines:

```
$respcont -split '\r?\n' |Select -Skip 4 |Select -SkipLast 9
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I'll keep using my `Select-String` part because I'm using a couple of different URLs from that API which all return slightly different contextual data. I wonder how in the future I can figure out myself if I'm dealing with a "single multi-line" string versus a "multiple single-line" string? The `.Length` operator is different (2307 versus 62), but how to deduce from this that you're either dealing with one or the other type of string?

Comment: @Moreaki The way you're using `Select-String` is perfectly fine - as long as the input are individual lines/strings :) For future reference, start by testing the type of the value in `$respcont`: `$respcont.GetType()` (will show you it's a `[string]` and not a `[string[]]` or `[object[]]`). To figure out whether a string is a "multi-line string" or not, simply test whether the same pattern matches: `$aSingleString -match '\r?\n'`